# Returning nth-order prime number in C++

Tags: c++

The helper function works well, yet the result always return me a number which is larger than the nth prime number by 1(except input = 1), i.e.

for n = 2, nth prime no. = 4

for n = 3, nth prime no. = 6, etc .

The following is my code.

```
bool helperFunction(int value) // Check whether the value is prime or not
{
  for(int i = 2; i<value; i++){
    if(value% i == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
        continue;
}
  return true;
}

int main()
{
  int input;                 //input = nth-order
  while(cin>>input){
  int result;
  int count = 1;

  cout<<endl;
  if(input == 1)
  {
      result = 2;
  }

  else{
      result = 3;
      while(count<input){
      if(helperFunction(result)==true)
          {
              count++;
              result++;
          }

      else
          result++;
      }
}
cout<<"result = "<< result;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please fix the indentation of your code?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is, that when you find the nth prime, and raise the count so it equals input, you also raise result. You have to either check if count '!=' / '<' input before result++, or decrease result by one before the end of the else loop.

I would also remove the "else continue;" part, since if it's not there the exact same thing happens.

The main logic might be nicer like this (I don't have a compiler at hand, but it should work I think):

```
result = 2;
while(count < input){ //if input == 1 no increment
    result++;
    if(helperFunction(result)) count++; // after 2 every new prime increments count
}
cout<<"result = "<< result;
```

Comment: @userAng: You are welcome. If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. – Usern4me 1 hour ago